# Newly created Eloquent object won't return attribute in separate create Eloquent call

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The code below shows a method in my Eloquent `Link` class. After creating a new `Link` I want to create a related object `LinkContact` then [`associate()`](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) it with the new `Link`.

When creating `LinkContact` I experience an issue in accessing the `Link`'s id attribute. The `Link` id value appears inaccessible only when performing the create method for the new related object (`LinkContact`).

Using Laravel Debugbar a line before the create method is called I've logged the `Link` id and I can see it just fine! Any ideas why this is happening and why I can't access the value?! Is it to do with scope?

Please take note of where the comments are

```
public function createActiveLink($students)
{
    $links = [];

    foreach ($students as $student) {
        $newLink = $this->create([
            'token'          => $student->saudi_nid,
            'status'         => 'active',
            'course_title'   => $student->course_title,
            'university_id'  => $student->university_id,
            'student_id'     => $student->id,
            'institution_id' => $student->institution_id,
            'course_id'      => $student->course_id,
        ]);

        $studentContacts = $student->institutionContacts;

        if ($studentContacts) {

            foreach ($studentContacts as $studentContact) {
                /* I get the value here, no problems */
                \Debugbar::info($newLink->id);

                $linkContact = $this->contacts()->create([
                    'type'                   => $studentContact->pivot->type,
                    'institution_contact_id' => $studentContact->pivot->institution_contact_id,
                    /* $newLink->id returns nothing here */
                    'link_id'                => $newLink->id, here!!
                ]);

                $newLink->contacts()->associate($linkContact);

                $newLink->save();
            }

        }

        $links[] = $newLink;
    }

    return $links;
}
```

The errors I receive when attempting the above code:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 
Column 'link_id' cannot be null 
(SQL: insert into `link_contacts` 
    (`type`, `institution_contact_id`, `link_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
     values (1, 1, , 2015-11-24 10:26:32, 2015-11-24 10:26:32))
C:\...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php#631

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 
Column 'link_id' cannot be null
C:\...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php#380
```

To reiterate I do get the value in Laravel Debugbar but not in the method call after it!

Edit:

In my `LinkContact` class `link_id` is in my fillable attributes:

```
class LinkContact extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['type', 'link_id', 'institution_contact_id'];

    // rest of the class
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth noting that:

```
$newLink->contacts()->associate($linkContact);
```

Would in this instance, run a query like:

```
UPDATE `link_contacts` SET `link_id` = 1 WHERE `id` = 4;
```

So if you're setting the `link_id` in the create, there's no need to run associate. If memory serves you may be able to run `$newLink->contacts()->create([...])` instead of both the `create()` and `associate()`.

Because of the way Eloquent works, a foreign key will always be updated/inserted from running any helper method designed to automatically insert this data but you're manually specifying the key, meaning that it's subject to `$fillable` so I would take a look at that, and if you don't currently have it in there, add `link_id` to that array.

Comment: thanks for your comment ollieread, `$newLink->contacts()->create([...])` was what I did originally, however, as I ran this code in `artisan tinker` previously the newly created related model doesn't show if I run `$newLink->contacts` and I thought the purpose of `associate()` was to allow `$newLink->contacts` to show the newly added relation. Perhaps I've misunderstood or my prior testing was incorrect?

Comment: Well, it wouldn't appear in `$newLink->contacts` during the same request as it wasn't loaded when you accessed it. For any request after it should do though.

Comment: Right, I'll see if I have access to the relation in data returned by the method.

Comment: ollieread, you're a boss - you were right, I do now have access to the relation after returning the data from the method. I'm guessing that if I needed direct access to the relation after adding it, would I be correct to use `$newLink->load('contacts')`?

Comment: You could use `load` but that would create an un-necessary call to the database. You could just manually add it to the collection, I do not recall how to do that right now, but that would be better.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$newLink->save();
```

before calling

```
$newLink->id
```

The id is generated only after the data was saved in the database so there's no way of knowing it before that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment George. Not disputing what you're saying and I'll give it a shot, but how is it possible for the value to be available one line of code prior to the method of where it is not available?!

Also, as I understood, create automatically will save to the database so the value should be available and I'm sure I've done this in my code before and I've never run code in eloquent where I've said, for example, `->create([$attr])` then after that said `->save()`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Maybe if you write a function that creates links and returns the id of the link then pass it in this foreach to your linkcontact structure?

Comment: As you suggested I ran `save()` after `create($attr)` but I get the same errors.

Comment: Create is the INSERT version of saves UPDATE, so the id would definitely be set after a create.